Is there any division operation in elliptic curve cryptography?
Suppose there are two points P and Q on an elliptic curve. For it, we have two operations.

Point addition $P + Q$
Point doubling $[2]P$ or $[2]Q$

Is there any way to get a reminder?
P%Q or division value P/Q?

We can define $P/Q$ as the smallest non-negative integer $k$ such that $$P=\underbrace{Q+Q+\dots+Q}_{k\text{ terms}}=[k]Q$$
For many curves commonly used in cryptography (including secp256k1 and secp256r1) this is well-defined, except for a special point $Q=\mathcal O$ named the neutral or point at infinity.
It's computationally possible to verify a guess of $k$ using
$$[k]Q=\begin{cases}\mathcal O&\text{if }k=0\\
Q&\text{if }k=1\\
[2]R\text{ where }R=[k/2]Q&\text{if }k\ge2\text{ and }k\text{ is even}\\
Q+R\text{ where }R=[k-1]Q&\text{if }k\ge3\text{ and }k\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$
Problem is, for curves used in cryptography, there's no known way to efficiently compute that $k=P/Q$ for arbitrary $P$, and the security of the curve relies on that.
If we want the usual $P\,\%\,Q=P-[P/Q]Q$, that leads to $P\,\%\,Q=\mathcal O$, which is not a very interesting operator.

We assume that we are talking about elliptic curves over a finite field.
Assume that there is an oracle $\mathcal{O}$ that answers the division(!)
then ask the $\mathcal{O}$ the pair $(P, G)$ to request $(P/G)$ where $P = [k]G$ then the oracle will output the $k$, which means you calculated the discrete log on the curve. So, whatever the division is defined in the other cases (!) (mod, real output etc.), you break the discrete log problem!
Therefore, we hope there is no such operation on the elliptic curves over a finite field.
Also keep in mind that, with scalar multiplication, the elliptic curve group forms a Z-Module, and we hope that they are not more than this. Similarly, we hope that they in the generic group model.

Too long for a comment:
The elliptic curve group $E$ is an additive group. So no division is defined with respect to points.
One operation you can define is, given some generator $G$ for the group if $P=k_P G,$ and $Q=k_Q G,$ you could compute $k_P k_Q^{-1}$ or $k_P \pmod{k_Q}$ over the integers modulo $n,$ where $n$ is the order of the generator, i.e., $n G={\cal O},$ where ${\cal O}$ is the point at infinity, the additive identity.
Is this what you are looking for? If you know both $k_P$ and $k_Q$ this is an easy computation. If you only know the elements $P,Q$ but not their discrete logs $k_P,k_Q$ with respect to the generator $G$ this should be hard. It should also be hard in general if you only know one of the discrete logs.

Yes you Can make division in finite field.
You want divide kP by kQ. You need to know kQ.
Exemple: finite field Z(29).
KQ=2 add +1 to Z 29+1=30 then divide by KQ 30/2=15. Multiply kP by 15 and you divide kP by 2. If kQ=3 30/3 multiply kP by 10. If kQ=4 (((29*3)+1)/4)=22 multiply kP by 22.
